# How to get from $1/θ \int_{x ≥0} x^n e^{(-x/θ)}dx$ to $θ^n \int_{x ≥0} x^n e^{-x}dx = n!θ^n$?

Tags: integration

How to get from $1/θ \int_{x ≥0} x^n e^{(-x/θ)}dx$ to $θ^n \int_{x ≥0} x^n e^{-x}dx = n!θ^n$?

I don't understand the manipulation done to turn $1/θ$ and $ e^{(-x/θ)}$ to $θ^n $ and $ e^{-x}$.

The one thing i do know is that $n! =\int_{x ≥0} x^n e^{-x/θ} dx$.

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: This is just a simple substitution: assuming $\theta > 0$ take $y = x/\theta$ so that $$\frac 1 \theta \int_{x ≥0} x^n e^{(-x/\theta)}dx = \theta^n \int_{y ≥0} y^n e^{-y}dy.$$

Comment: @Umberto P. Cheers!